# TweetAdapter not fetching information from TweetListActivity

Tags: android

I have been taking this Android tutorial at [CodeLearn](http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial) and have faced a problem. I have searched all through the Internet and I can't seem to find any answer for this.

Here's the code for the TweetListActivity:

```
package com.arvisapps.aryansh.encryptit;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


 public class TweetListActivity extends ListActivity
{
    private String[] stringArray;
    private ArrayAdapter tweetItemArrayAdapter;
    private List<Tweet> tweets;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tweet_list);


    tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        Tweet tweet = new Tweet();
        tweet.setTitle("Header #" + i);
        Log.d("Fuck Me", "Title captured " + tweet.getTitle());
        tweet.setBody("Body text #" + i);
        tweets.add(tweet);
    }

    tweetItemArrayAdapter = new TweetAdapter(this, tweets);
    setListAdapter(tweetItemArrayAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TweetDetailActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

Here's the code for TweetAdapter:

```
    package com.arvisapps.aryansh.encryptit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;



public class TweetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tweet> {
String headerSet;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public TweetAdapter(Activity activity, List<Tweet> tweets) {
    super(activity, R.layout.row_tweet, tweets);
    inflater = activity.getWindow().getLayoutInflater();

}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_tweet, parent, false);

    Tweet tweet = new Tweet();
    headerSet = tweet.getTitle();
    Log.d("Text Captured", "Text Captured "+headerSet);
    ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tweetTitle)).setText(headerSet);
    return convertView;

}

}
```

Here's an additional POJO:

```
    package com.arvisapps.aryansh.encryptit;


public class Tweet
{
private String id;
private String title;
private String body;

public void setTitle(String title)
{
    this.title = title;
}

public String getTitle()
{
    return this.title;
}

public void setBody(String body)
{
    this.body = body;
}

public String getBody()
{
    return this.body;
}

public void setId(String id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getId()
{
    return this.id;
}
}
```

The problem is that when I check the logcat for TweetListActivity it shows the right text, i.e, the text I need as an output but in TweetAdapter upon checking the Logcat the same text is nullified, i.e, it is displayed as null in the logcat. I want that the text in TweetAdapter to be what it is in the TweetListActivity.

Comment: It worked Jason G Peterson! I don't know why you deleted your answer.

Comment: I am also learning app development from codelearn.org and got stuck at same lesson 17. Can you share the solution??